# ZF2 Translation inside autoload dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, zend-framework, zend-framework2, translation, autoload

I've got a ZF2 project with basic/skeleton structure. I've got `/var/www/project/module/Application/language` with a languages and
`/var/www/project/config/autoload/dictionaries.php` which contain month names and so on.

I need to translate values of dictionary to desired language. I have tried to make it the same way as I did inside View `/var/www/project/module/Application/view/application/module-name/×××.phtml`:

```
$this->plugin('translate')->getTranslator()->setLocale('en_US'); 
$this->translate("foreign language staff");
```

But `$this` have no idea what I'm talking about. Then I try the way I try it inside Controllers `/var/www/project/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/ModuleController.php`:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

class CompanyController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction() {
        $translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
        define('LOCALE', substr($translator->getLocale(),0,5));
        $translator->setLocale(LOCALE);
        $translator->addTranslationFile('gettext', '/....../language/' . LOCALE . '.mo', 'messages', LOCALE);

        $translator->translate("foreign language staff"),
```

But no in the dictionary neither in Controller I can not get translate, even addTranslationFile file path and LOCALE is correctly settled.

Comment: I think you are not calling the module correct way `$translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;` to `$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('translate');`

Comment: As far as I remember, you can use the translate function with $this->translate(YOURTEXT); or with _(YOURTEXT). I remember using the _(YOURTEXT) in some files where no servicelocator was available.